# D3 JSON paths and SVGs

Tags: json, d3.js, path, maps

After some wrestling, I have managed to put together a JSON file that can draw me a map of London and its boroughs. It's here http://graphitti.org/admin2/files/experiments/03_scaledTM5.html

Apart from the fact that the boundaries aren't perfect, the map seems OK but there's a problem in that some, but not all, of the paths apparently take up the whole SVG space. So when I inspect them in the DOM, I end up selecting the whole area. Likewise if I were to colour them in with a fill, I'd turn the whole space that colour.

I've noticed that this tends to happen with the larger boroughs, and the smaller ones are selectable through the DOM. That's not always true, but is there some limit to the number of coordinates that D3 can handle here? Or is there something else up with the code?
the JSON is here http://www.graphitti.org/admin2/files/experiments/EWNI2.json if anyone wants to inspect it. City of London is a "good" borough, as are Hackney and Tower Hamlets. Most of the others, eg Barnet, Barking, are "bad" in that they fill the SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your paths are "inside-out" as far as the d3 mapping functions are concerned.  [The order of points in a path or sub-path has to be clockwise](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#wiki-_path) for it to get mapped properly.

Counter-clockwise loops are interpretted as "holes" within a larger shape, the bounds of which are assumed to be outside the map.  As a result, when you colour in the shape, everything *except* the area within the path gets coloured.

The docs recommend running your GeoJSON file through [this utility](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_ForceRHR.html) to re-order the vertices in the correct structure.  Of course, you could also write your own utility to reverse the order, and just manually go through and figure out which ones are incorrect.

Comment: That's great,thanks. Rather shamefully, I don't understand what I'm supposed to do with that utility you've linked to -is it gdal thing? As I've tried to get to grips with that stuff and I'm so out of my depth it's not true

Comment: Sorry, I'd copied the link without looking at it too closely.  Looks like it's not a stand-alone utility but a function within PostGIS.  Maybe try converting to [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference) and back?  (Requires node.js).  Or just figure out which shapes are inside-out, and replace their coordinates array with the same array `.reverse()`'d.  Then stringify your JSON, write it to the screen, copy, paste, and save.  If you're not a mapping software expert (and I'm certainly not), that might be easiest for a small dataset like this.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. I really can't wait to get these maps sorted out and then I can just reuse them. GIS really is a whole 'nother world...

Comment: Okay, I seem to have finally got the script to test and reverse the coordinate strings working.  But it's reversing everything -- including the shapes which weren't displaying strangely on your map.  Give it a go: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9GpQG/5/  It should work on any dataset where each feature is a single polygon, with no holes or islands.